# A simple Node JS Application, but the header and footer Partials not working

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am a beginner Node.js developer and i'm coding a Simple app with node.js and express framework. In order to reduce code redundancy, I'm using a partial folder in order to store the header.ejs and footer.ejs. I'm trying to call these partials by:  `<%- include('partials/header') %>`. When restarting the server, the above syntax is displayed instead of the actual header.

I've watched multiple videos online an tried several different ways of implementing this, though none worked till now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
      <%- include partials/header %>
   <main>
    <div><p>. . .</p></div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h3>MY TIMETABLE - <em>Section Under Construction</em></h3>

        <p>The main page, where the student will be able to see all venues and lecturers throughout the semester. A Map is also considered, in order to help them pin down the venue and avoid confusion.</p>
      </div>
    </main>
    <%- include partials/footer %>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I believe you want to include those partials **inside** body.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko  I included the partials inside the body tags but still, the syntax is being outputted

Answer (score 0):

Your partials are outside of the body of your HTML document. They need to be inside the body tags.